# Is it fruitful to apply cross-validation on big-datasets?

Tags: cross-validation

I have a big dataset, and I would to know whether it's better to apply cross-validation or the common split (at example) 70%-15%-15% on training, validation and test set.
More precisely: CV is a good practice only with small dataset, or it could be useful with big dataset too?

Comment: CV lets you use more of the data, at the cost of extra computation. Use CV when you can, simple holdout if computationally infeasible.